# Outlook 2007 TreeView in Windows Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

im trying to build my first application on Windows forms with C#. Im fighting against the `TreeView` `Control` and MS outlook 2007...

I need a `TreeView` like the Explorer in Outlook 2007, the  exchange public folders preselected.

I have created the parent `Node`, but i have problems to get all child nodes.

Now, Im getting only the first level

I started with this code:

```
private void TreeViewOutlookPublicFolders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initalisieren der Oulook Session
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace OlNs = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder StartFolder = OlNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders);


    // Display a wait cursor while the TreeNodes are being created.
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    // Suppress repainting the TreeView until all the objects have been created.
    TreeViewOutlookPublicFolders.BeginUpdate();

    // Clear the TreeView each time the method is called.
    TreeViewOutlookPublicFolders.Nodes.Clear();

    TreeNode TRoot = TreeViewOutlookPublicFolders.Nodes.Add(StartFolder.Name);

    foreach ( Folder f in StartFolder.Folders)
    {
        Debug.Print(f.Name);
        TRoot.Nodes.Add(f.Name);
    }

    // Reset the cursor to the default for all controls.
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

    // Begin repainting the TreeView.
    TreeViewOutlookPublicFolders.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive286.html) that may explain what it is you're trying to do. Take a look and see if this helps you.

Can you elaborate a bit on what you're "fighting against" with the `Treeiew`? You've created the parent and child nodes I'm assuming, but is your problem that you're unable to open the form with a folder preselected or something else?

Comment: I have created the parent node, but i have problem to get the child nodes.. the problem is teh beginning, i guess